# Select all layers in wms url

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, wms

I have a wms url and want to show all the layers. My question is: How can I do it without specifying every layer in param?

My sample query is:

```
hillshade3: {
    name: 'Hillshade Europa 3',
    type: 'wms',
    url: 'http://giswebservices.massgis.state.ma.us/geoserver/wms?VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&SRS=EPSG:26986&BBOX=11830.0,776202.9449152543,348201.0,961492.0550847457&WIDTH=708&HEIGHT=390&INFO_FORMAT=text/javascript&FEATURE_COUNT=10&QUERY_LAYERS=massgis:GISDATA.ACECS_POLY&X=120&Y=109&FORMAT&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS',
    layerOptions: {
        layers: 'layers',
        format: 'image/png'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

**layers** (in layerOptions) is a request parameter to your WMS provider ...

The specification is [here](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms) and states that layers is a Comma-separated list of one or more map layers.
No mention of a special name for **all** layers.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to ask the provider to add a layers called "all".
It's a good thing to tell them that it saves their computer if all layers are often requested not to merge a large number of pictures on each request.